# Would extracting logs from a European server to a US SIEM system cause privacy legal concerns?

Tags: legal, logging, siem, log-analysis

Looking for an answer related to the European "General Data Protection Regulation." laws.

Comment: I'm thinking this is less of a security question and more of a legal question. We're not lawyers, you might want to consult your legal department or an independent lawyer for a concrete answer.